# Не получается написать функцию. Пример и условия вложены. Спасибо

Tags: ios, swift

```
func arr(line: Int) {
    let mas = Array(1...line)
    for i in mas {
        if i < 5 || i >= 10 && i < 15 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Функции необходимо выводить значения
от 1...N, если < 5,  < 15, < 25, ... <N
Вывод на консоль: 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто проверяйте, чтобы остаток от деления на 10 был меньше 5:

```swift
func arr(line: Int) {
    let mas = Array(1...line)
    for i in mas {
        if i % 10 < 5 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

arr(line: 25)
```